Laravel Create a new Xlsx file from a template with multiple sheets
I am looking to modify an xlsx file that contains tables, images, logos, hyperlinks, colors, formulas, and charts. I want to be able to edit the data in the tables and add a logo. I've experimented with several packages, but none seem to fully meet my needs. While Templator works, it has some flaws.
Is there a way to achieve this using PHPSpreadsheet?
Specifically, I need to:
Load an xlsx file.
Modify the status row by row, which contains formulas affecting other rows and sheets.
Trigger the chart rendering on the last sheet.
I attempted this with Spreadsheet, but encountered issues such as sometimes losing images, logos, tables,charts and blanks pages.
Can anyone provide assistance?
I tried laravel Excel -> dont have
phpSpreadSheet -> chart doesnt load, some blank pages, hyperlink missing
laravel templator -> formula doesnt load immediately, data between rows goes missing, sheet doesnt update from another sheet

I feel like it should be doable with PHPSpreadsheet. Also, Laravel Excel is just a wrapper on top of PHPSpreadsheet so the functionality is the same.

it can be done but its removing the styles and charts
